# Particular value in a JQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [JQueryGantt](https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt) library and looking in the source code I found as `value` of some `<input>` element, values like these `(#=obj.code?obj.code:''#)`. I haven't seen nothing like this in javascript. What are these?

Comment: i just searched all js files in https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt for the pattern you describe but found nothing, in which are these?

Comment: Sorry, retry with this `(#=obj.code?obj.code:''#)` which as the same syntax.

Comment: Looks like a ternary operator

Comment: Ok, but the `#=obj.code`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its for the JST jquery template engine, this way you can access properties of the object, in this case a "TASKROW" and renders the value, check the lines 30 to 47 to see how it is parsed and executed

https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt/blob/52bc859bab0866a45b2e233b5783ed8d7046ae4b/libs/jquery/JST/jquery.JST.js

the object is defined for usuage with the templating engine

```
var taskRow = $.JST.createFromTemplate(task, "TASKROW");
```

and in the template you see

```
<div class="__template__" type="TASKROW"><!--
  <tr taskId="(#=obj.id#)" class="taskEditRow (#=obj.isParent()?'isParent':''#) (#=obj.collapsed?'collapsed':''#)" level="(#=level#)">
```

Comment: Thanks John, if you think that the question could be useful, please upvote!